# How does the console output determined

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm fairly new to Scheme and I'm using `DrRacket` as my IDE.

If i have a small program, for example - a program that's given a number, would generate a list from 0 to that number:

```
(define (helper num mylist)
  (cond [(zero? num) (append (list 0) mylist)]
        [else (helper (- num 1) (append (list num) mylist))]))
(define (genlist num)
  (helper num '()))
```

> (genlist 10) => '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)

I'm coming from a Java background, and there is obviously no `print` statement here. So how does it "decide" to output `mylist` to the console? What "tells" it to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`genlist` doesn't print the list, it only returns it. It's the REPL that prints it because it prints the return value of whichever expression you enter.

It also prints the values of any non-void expressions that are written at the top level of your file when you load it.

Comment: @Gambit2007 also note that such top lever printing is special for `#lang racket` and that a `#!r6rs` top level program wouldn't print anything not explicitly printed when run,  only when entered in a repl. You have [Java repl too](http://www.javarepl.com/console.html)

Comment: Alright thanks, i'll keep that in mind! So far it looks like i'll be using only `#lang racket`

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter (REPL) always prints the value of the expression you entered.

If we define

```
(define (foo a)
  (display a)
  a)

(define (bar a)
  (display a))
```

we get the output

```
> (bar "hello")
hello
> (foo "hello")
hello"hello"
```

where the `hello`s (without quotation marks) are output by the procedures, and then the REPL prints the result of the procedure calls, which is nothing for the first, and `"hello"` for the second.
In DrRacket, the outputs also have different colours.

(Also note that a string that is a value is printed differently from a string that is a procedure's output.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well!